# Creating two types of data at once in a single resolver (Graphql + Prisma)

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

When a user creates a data of type Post, I need the graphql server to automatically create a data of type Commit as well. The type Commit connects to type User and type Post. Here is the graphql pattern for type User, type Post, and type Commit:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  commits: [Commit!]!
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String
  commits: [Commit!]!
}

type Commit {
  id: ID!
  user: User!
  post: Post!
}
```

So I made a createPost mutation. The createPost mutation must do two jobs at once: creating the Post, and then creating the Commit. The Commit data should connect to the newly created Post data. Below is the resolver that I have came up with until now:

```
Mutation: {
  createPost: async (_, args) => {
    const {user, title, content} = args;
    await prisma.createPost({
      title,
      content
    });
    const postId = await prisma.post({title}).id();
    await prisma.createCommit({
      user: {connect: {id: user.id}},
      post: {connect: {id: postId }}
    });
    const newPost = await prisma.post({id:postId});
    return newPost;
  }
}
```

Is this an effective way? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work as well:

```
Mutation: {
  createPost: async (_, args) => {
    const {user, title, content} = args;
    const post = await prisma.createPost({
      title,
      content
    });
    await prisma.createCommit({
      user: {connect: {id: user.id}},
      post: {connect: {id: post.id }}
    });
    return post;
  }
}
```

Prisma returns the record created so you don't need to query for it again.